# Selenium WebDriver - waiting for angular requests(Java)

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, selenium, automated-tests

I am creating tests for angular based app and I need help.
I have to create a wait which will be waiting until all pending requests will be processed. 
Basically in my scenario I want to mark a checkbox but it is only available when  GET requests are finished, if I use simple `Thread.sleep(2000)` everything is working fine, but I know it is not reliable way to solve this.
i tried two approaches:

First:

```
   AdditionalConditions wait = new AdditionalConditions();
        wait.untilAngularFinishHttpCalls();



 public void untilAngularFinishHttpCalls() {
        final String javaScriptToLoadAngular =
                "var injector = window.angular.element('app-root').injector();" +
                        "var $http = injector.get('$http');" +
                        "return ($http.pendingRequests.length === 0)";

        ExpectedCondition<Boolean> pendingHttpCallsCondition = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(javaScriptToLoadAngular).equals(true);
            }
        };
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(SharedDriver.getDriver(), 20); // timeout = 20 secs
        wait.until(pendingHttpCallsCondition);
    }
```

And here I get following error:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Cannot read
>   property 'element' of undefined (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763
>   (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.15063 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 5 milliseconds Build info:
>   version: '2.31.0', revision:
>   '1bd294d185a80fa4206dfeab80ba773c04ac33c0', time: '2013-02-27
>   13:51:26' System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64',
>   os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities
>   [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false,
>   mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false,
>   chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.31.488763
>   (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),
>   userDataDir=C:\Users\lpaczek\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir13872_15975},
>   takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal,
>   databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false,
>   version=59.0.3071.115, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false,
>   nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true,
>   webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true,
>   javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, setWindowRect=true,
>   unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]

And I tried also:

```
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(SharedDriver.getDriver(), 15, 500);
        wait.until(AdditionalConditions.angularHasFinishedProcessing());


public class AdditionalConditions {
    public static ExpectedCondition<Boolean> angularHasFinishedProcessing() {
        return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return Boolean.valueOf(((JavascriptExecutor)
                        driver).executeScript("return (window.angular !== undefined) && (angular.element(document).injector() !== undefined) && (angular.element(document).injector(). get('$http').pendingRequests.length === 0)").toString());
            }
        };
    }
```

And here i get Timeout after 15 second.It seems that it does not work. 
Please help if you can, as far as I know I need to execute JavaScript code and I am newbie in it.

Comment: Instead of adding explicit wait for each and every angular calls, can we handle all those in implicit wait alone?

Answer (score 0):

you can wait for angular to finish it work

the [ngwebDriver](https://github.com/paul-hammant/ngWebDriver) package will give you that ability

```
var driver = new NgWebDriver(driver);

driver.waitForAngularRequestsToFinish();
```

Comment: I've added it to my code and I get "org.openqa.selenium.ScriptTimeoutException: asynchronous script timeout: result was not received in 15 seconds"

Why? when I test it manually the requests are processed after ~6 seconds

Comment: this is application specific... cant tell from the question

Answer (score 0):

you can try solution that was proposed in https://www.swtestacademy.com/selenium-wait-javascript-angular-ajax/

also can be found on https://github.com/swtestacademy/JSWaiter (see JSWaiter.java) but might be outdated in comparison with article

```
public class JSWaiter {
    private static WebDriver jsWaitDriver;
    private static WebDriverWait jsWait;
    private static JavascriptExecutor jsExec;
    //Get the driver 
    public static void setDriver (WebDriver driver) {
        jsWaitDriver = driver;
        jsWait = new WebDriverWait(jsWaitDriver, 10);
        jsExec = (JavascriptExecutor) jsWaitDriver;
    }
   private void ajaxComplete() {
        jsExec.executeScript("var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];"
            + "var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();" + "xhr.open('GET', '/Ajax_call', true);"
            + "xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {" + "  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {"
            + "    callback(xhr.responseText);" + "  }" + "};" + "xhr.send();");
    }
    private void waitForJQueryLoad() {
        try {
            ExpectedCondition<Boolean> jQueryLoad = driver -> ((Long) ((JavascriptExecutor) this.driver)
                .executeScript("return jQuery.active") == 0);
            boolean jqueryReady = (Boolean) jsExec.executeScript("return jQuery.active==0");
            if (!jqueryReady) {
                jsWait.until(jQueryLoad);
            }
        } catch (WebDriverException ignored) {
        }
    }
    private void waitForAngularLoad() {
        String angularReadyScript = "return angular.element(document).injector().get('$http').pendingRequests.length === 0";
        angularLoads(angularReadyScript);
    }
    private void waitUntilJSReady() {
        try {
            ExpectedCondition<Boolean> jsLoad = driver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) this.driver)
                .executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().equals("complete");
            boolean jsReady = jsExec.executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().equals("complete");
            if (!jsReady) {
                jsWait.until(jsLoad);
            }
        } catch (WebDriverException ignored) {
        }
    }
    private void waitUntilJQueryReady() {
        Boolean jQueryDefined = (Boolean) jsExec.executeScript("return typeof jQuery != 'undefined'");
        if (jQueryDefined) {
            poll(20);
            waitForJQueryLoad();
            poll(20);
        }
    }
    public void waitUntilAngularReady() {
        try {
            Boolean angularUnDefined = (Boolean) jsExec.executeScript("return window.angular === undefined");
            if (!angularUnDefined) {
                Boolean angularInjectorUnDefined = (Boolean) jsExec.executeScript("return angular.element(document).injector() === undefined");
                if (!angularInjectorUnDefined) {
                    poll(20);
                    waitForAngularLoad();
                    poll(20);
                }
            }
        } catch (WebDriverException ignored) {
        }
    }
    public void waitUntilAngular5Ready() {
        try {
            Object angular5Check = jsExec.executeScript("return getAllAngularRootElements()[0].attributes['ng-version']");
            if (angular5Check != null) {
                Boolean angularPageLoaded = (Boolean) jsExec.executeScript("return window.getAllAngularTestabilities().findIndex(x=>!x.isStable()) === -1");
                if (!angularPageLoaded) {
                    poll(20);
                    waitForAngular5Load();
                    poll(20);
                }
            }
        } catch (WebDriverException ignored) {
        }
    }
    private void waitForAngular5Load() {
        String angularReadyScript = "return window.getAllAngularTestabilities().findIndex(x=>!x.isStable()) === -1";
        angularLoads(angularReadyScript);
    }
    private void angularLoads(String angularReadyScript) {
        try {
            ExpectedCondition<Boolean> angularLoad = driver -> Boolean.valueOf(((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
                .executeScript(angularReadyScript).toString());
            boolean angularReady = Boolean.valueOf(jsExec.executeScript(angularReadyScript).toString());
            if (!angularReady) {
                jsWait.until(angularLoad);
            }
        } catch (WebDriverException ignored) {
        }
    }
    public void waitAllRequest() {
        waitUntilJSReady();
        ajaxComplete();
        waitUntilJQueryReady();
        waitUntilAngularReady();
        waitUntilAngular5Ready();
    }
    /**
     * Method to make sure a specific element has loaded on the page
     *
     * @param by
     * @param expected
     */
    public void waitForElementAreComplete(By by, int expected) {
        ExpectedCondition<Boolean> angularLoad = driver -> {
            int loadingElements = this.driver.findElements(by).size();
            return loadingElements >= expected;
        };
        jsWait.until(angularLoad);
    }
    /**
     * Waits for the elements animation to be completed
     * @param css
     */
    public void waitForAnimationToComplete(String css) {
        ExpectedCondition<Boolean> angularLoad = driver -> {
            int loadingElements = this.driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(css)).size();
            return loadingElements == 0;
        };
        jsWait.until(angularLoad);
    }
    private void poll(long milis) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(milis);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```